# TCP/IP statistics using libpcap

Tags: tcp, libpcap

I need to monitor *TCP packet statistics* on Linux/Windows using libpcap (WinpCap).
Specifically, I have been instructed to research the possibility of monitoring TCP traffic on a machine, and determining the following statistics:

**1) # of packets based on port number**

This is easy. The source/dest port numbers are in the TCP header.

**2) Average/Minimum/Maximum response times**

Problematic.

Question: What, exactly, defines a “response time” at the TCP level?
If we are talking about monitoring ACKs at the TCP level, then we would have to keep track of packet sequence numbers for a connection, and understand how TCP actually works in detail. *Correct*?

**3) # of retransmissions**

Problematic.

*Question*: What, exactly, defines a “retransmission” at the TCP level?

**4) # of errors**

Problematic.

*Question*: What, exactly, defines an “error” at the TCP level?